# generate matrix-like graph with d3.js

Tags: matrix, d3.js, rect

I have a matrix, each cell has an RGB value. I want to project that matrix onto a corresponding rectangular graph, based on each matrix cell's RGB value. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created an example of how to create a grid in d3.js at http://bl.ocks.org/2605010. It includes the code to color the cells by setting the fill.